# jQuery .ajax request failing

Tags: jquery

I currently have a jQuery ajax request set up like this

```
$(document).ready(
    function() { $.ajax({ 
        url : "http://www.my-computer.com:51000/getJson",
        cache : false,
        dataType: "json",
        success : renderPage,
        error: handleError
    })
});
```

If I manually naviate to http://www.my-computer.com:51000/getJson, I see it returns a json string correctly, but with the above request, I always fall into "handleError" method, with textStatus "error" and not much helpful information. Can anyone help? Thanks!

EDIT: sorry about the my-computer domain. this stackoverflow submission won't let me input localhost, so I put in an arbitrary domain instead. I've tried firebug, but had no luck in getting the json back.

Comment: You haven't set dataType.  The best way to figure out what's wrong with .ajax (or indeed, any javascript) is to try it in Firefox with Firebug enabled.

Comment: I havent used Firebug, but in chrome/safari, with the developer tools, you can check every request in the tab "Network". Check if the status is OK, and what the response contains. (Click XHR on the bottom to filter if you have many requests on your page)

Comment: The status goes to "cancelled" after it runs through the handleError function, but I am not sure why since I can access the url directly. What are some things that could be wrong? Thanks..

Comment: Hm, I can't see any other solution than that the backend is not responding well to a json request, or that it is using wrong HTTP status codes. Are you using Rails or something as the backend? Any code?

Comment: Post your backend code. Only then can it be analyzed...

Comment: The two most likely culprits are 1) the request is cross-origin due to a domain, protocol, or port difference (e.g., your page is hosted on domain foo.com, but the page being fetched over Ajax sits on domain bar.com), or 2) the result being fetched is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding  clientaccesspolicy.xml file to the root with the following in it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

I am also using a div to display any error messages in, for debugging purposes, as that might help you to see what error message in in the JSON String:

```
function GetShoppingCartData() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DesktopModules/EcomDnnProducts/AjaxProductDisplay.aspx/GetShoppingCartData",
        data: "{'CartId': '" + jQuery(".shoppingcartid").attr("value") + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            buildShoppingCart(msg.d);
        },
        fail: function (msg) {
            jQuery('#productattributesdata').text(msg.d);
        }
    });
}
```

In my .net code, I had to add the following to the web.config file:

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
```

hth

Answer (score -3):

Your code is broken. Note only do you have one more `{` than `}`, the way you've coded it is all wrong. Also, what domain are you trying to send this request from? If you're sending it from a domain other than my-computer.com, then your request will fail. If not, try this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$.ajax({

        url : "http://www.my-computer.com:51000/getJson",
        cache : false,
        data: "json",
        success : renderPage,
        error: handleError
    })
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on sending it from a domain other than my-computer.com? Can I not send the request to a different domain? (I'm sending it to localhost, but I'm curious). Thanks!

Comment: the `});` on the bottom is from your code, but he has removed the `$(document).ready(function() {` part. So the code in the question is ok, but not in this answer.

Comment: This is not an answer at all, changing the code is not going to make his error to go away as he explained.